# Why is my lambda capturing a pointer by value?

Tags: c++11, lambda

I have the following lambda

```
    direction->addClickEventListener([=](Ref* sender){

        std::unordered_map<int,int> data;
        rep->getData(DIRECTION, data);
        int last = data[1];
        int rotation = (last + 45)%360;

        LOG("l:%i r:%i",last,rotation);//Always logs l:0 r:45
        direction->setRotation(rotation);
        data[1] = rotation;
        rep->setData(DIRECTION, data);
    });
```

where getData is:

```
void getData(DATA_KEY key,std::unordered_map<int,int>& data){
//Modifies data with the appropriate values for key, for the current state of rep
}

void setData(DATA_KEY key,std::unordered_map<int,int>& data){
//Makes a copy of data stores it internally with key
}
```

rep is pointer, so I thought that whenever the lambda is called, the current value of data will always reflect the current state of rep. But it seems that it is always the value of whatever rep was at the time direction->addClickEventListener was called.

If I want to use the current state of rep, how ghouls I modify my lambda ? 
EDIT: Since rep is a pointer, I can't can't capture by reference..

Comment: Why would you not be able to have a reference to a pointer variable? You could easily have something like `some_type*& ref_to_ptr = some_pointer;` The problem more likely have to do with the function where the variable `rep` was defined in might return before your lambda is called, which would have given you a dangling reference to a non-existing variable. If you capture by value then as long as the data the pointer `rep` is pointing to is valid, then you won't have dangling or invalid references.

Comment: wait a minute... is addClickEventListener a template? I understand that  your lambda works  like some kind of callback function. How do you store it? Issue is that lambdas, even while having same parameters and return type, they will be objects of different type, because they may use different external  variables. If you're not using template or function<> from <functional> to wrap around your callable,  I'm not sure how that will work. What would happen, if some casting is used  to store, then call callback by stored pointer, is unknown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointer doesn't have state, methods or something. Pointer is abstract address  of storage where your object is. "Reference" is synonymous to pointer in some ways, if you think in C terms, but they are different in C++ - you *can* pass pointer variable by reference, thus passing control over its value (not over the state of object it points to, that actually achieved by pointer). Pointer variable is also a storage, that contains value of pointer 
You can pass any variable (storage) "by reference", which means that function can change value stored in that variable. In C that was done by passing pointers, but to pass pointer "by reference" they had to  pass type like `void**`  pointer to a pointer. In C++ & syntax is used to reduce the clutter.

- `[=]` mans that all external variables are captured by value. This would allow  anonymous function to read value of pointer, deference it and call methods\access fields of the objects it points to.
- `[&]` would mean  capture by reference. Pointer is variable. This would allow lamba to modify it, making it to point to other object.

If you do need only rep by reference use, [=. &rep].
How rep might be changed while lambda is running? If that happens in parallel thread, you'll probably need an atomic.

If you cannot change actual object your pointer  refers to, that may mean that compiler does aliasing optimization because of illegal cast from one object to another, because casted away const modifier or low quality of implementation (that's rare) that causes aliasing optimization where it should not happen.

Comment: @John - capturing action wise is equivalent of passing parameters to function. Except you not define function, do not give its name and list of formal parameters - that's all done by compiler. IF rep is local variable and lambda is called when its  lifetime is over, I don't see why you want to track its state.

Comment: @John  formal parameters, passed by value, _are_ local variables, automatic storage(most likely passed in register). Only value of poniter was passed then. Their life ends with exit of function you can't pass them\capture them by reference to a callable (lambda or not) that would be run out of scope they exist in. Some programmer dude is absolutely correct in that you get proper state of the object with pointer passed by value, what you can't do is to change that pointer to "aim" it to another object.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, so this might not be an answer to your problem, but it is an attempt to clarify what the problem with capturing by reference is.

It looks like you are having an event-based system. The important thing to know about events is that they can occur at any time.

Now lets say you have something like this (very simplified and pseudo-ish):

```
void some_function(some_type* rep)
{
    add_event_listener([&]()
    {
        do_something(rep);
    });
}
```

There is a very serious bug in the code above: When the event is invoked and the lambda is called, the function `some_function` will have returned, and therefore the scope of the ***local variable*** `rep` doesn't exist any more. So when `rep` is used in the lambda it is a reference to a variable that doesn't exist anymore (remember that `rep` is a *local* variable). That of course leads to *undefined behavior*.

If you capture by value instead, the pointer is *copied* meaning you now have *two* pointer variables, both pointing to the same memory. Then it doesn't matter if the first variable goes out of scope, because the second variable still is valid.

Comment: @John If the data pointed to by `rep` is valid and existing when the lambda is called, then modifying that data should work. Maybe you have some other UB somewhere else that leads to problems? Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's really impossible to say. Have you tried using memory debuggers (like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) On POSIX platforms) to make sure there is no problem with your pointers or memory handling?

Comment: The function containing the lambda is in another object than rep, and is called while rep is being constructed (I am passing rep into the function as a parameter)...

Comment: @John, possible reasons for that underlying object is not changed that you break https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing - strict aliasing rule there when assigning pointer. Some Programmer dude, how you do add those hyperlinks to comments? o.O

Comment: @Swift When writing a comment, click the "help" link under the "Add Comment" button to see how. :)